# Prefixing IDs and Classes with Element Types in CSS

Tags: css, class, coding-style, standards

Hopefully this question falls under the Q/A rules here.

I was hoping that people could shed some light on the benefits of prefixing selectors in the css markup, and disadvantages of it.

For example

```
div.body-content {
    color: #fff;
}
```

or

```
.body-content {
    color: #fff;
}
```

So would people care to shed some light on their opinions on both these styles of coding, will help me consider how I code as well as others looking at coding styles/techniques.

Comment: Its depends on situation. Some time you need it when you having this class on other element types. But Some time It could be "Overqualifying selectors", which is not good. Its always depends.

Answer (score 0):

it can help if you use the same class in different place.

for exemple :

```
tr .class    //for a tab
a .class     //for a link
```

also, it can help you remember where did you used it

Answer (score 0):

A class selector is a selector that uses a defined class (multiple per page).

**E.g.** `p.section` in

p.section { padding: 10px; }

and you apply `.section` in every p tag than it's apply . Only for p tag

`.section{padding:10px;}` this class is apply any tag of html and div etc .

Now more **[about this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)**